# Example command to set same DSCP value in the IP header for return packets within the same TCP connection

Tags: iptables, tc, netfilter, qos

I have seen connmark or ctinfo could work for this but couldn't find a simple effective command to make it work (Not familiar within this area).

The command can be applied to the TCP termination node or any linux node as intermediary router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m dscp --dscp-class AF12 -j CONNMARK --set-xmark 12
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -m connmark --mark 12 -j DSCP --set-dscp-class AF12
```

(not 100% dynamic as the DSCP value need to be known in advance in order to get a match)

Comment: I'm waiting to see when this [patchset](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/list/?series=162088&state=* "Support for boolean binops with variable RHS operands") lands (in linux 5.7?) if it's possible to have a generic method using nftables instead.